# Asp.net Push notifications

Tags: android, asp.net, azure, push-notification

Push notifications doesn't get received on my android app.I tried many providers but I'm still couldn't get it to work. 
No since my backend is in Asp.net I thought of using Azure push hub, I'm not sure where to start. and also I have a little experience on push notifications. How would I go for sending a simple push like "check that update" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amr Alaa: You can go with azure notification hub. it has very simple implementation.

you can create notification hub in azure.by going to New > app service > service bus> notification hub > Quick create > give hub name > create

latter you can use bellow code in your asp.net application/api (doesn't matter it is on azure or not.)

```
//you can create class and get instance of the hub in constructor

    private NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Your connectionstring", "your Notification hub name");
```

from your android app while starting of the app call this method with divice token.

```
public async string registerpushhandle(string handle = null)
    {

        try
        {


            string newRegistrationId = null;

            if (handle != null)
            {
                var registrations = await hub.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(handle, 500);

                foreach (RegistrationDescription registration in registrations)
                {
                    if (newRegistrationId == null)
                    {
                        newRegistrationId = registration.RegistrationId;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await hub.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registration);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (newRegistrationId == null) newRegistrationId = await hub.CreateRegistrationIdAsync();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
        return newRegistrationId 
    }
```

after getting registration id call this method by passing your registrationid, plateform, and device token.

```
public async void registerpushid(string id, string platform, string handle)
        {


            try
            {

                RegistrationDescription registration = null;
                switch (platform.ToLower())
                {
                    case "mpns":
                        registration = new MpnsRegistrationDescription(handle);
                        break;
                    case "wns":
                        registration = new WindowsRegistrationDescription(handle);
                        break;
                    case "apns":
                        registration = new AppleRegistrationDescription(handle);
                        break;
                    case "gcm":
                        registration = new GcmRegistrationDescription(handle);
                        break;

                }

                registration.RegistrationId = id;



                registration.Tags = new HashSet<string>();
                registration.Tags.Add(handle);
                 registration.Tags.Add("yourcustometag");


                try
                {
                    await hub.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registration);


                }
                catch (MessagingException e)
                {

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Amr, you can use pushsharp (https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp), its a complete library to send push notifications to Android, iOS, etc.

Here's a guide to configure and get it running:
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-GCM-Google-Cloud-Messaging-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp

I've used it in a couple of projects, with great results.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try the following links as they provide completely free unlimited push notification from Android & are pretty simple to implement:

https://onesignal.com/

https://pushover.net/

http://rzlts.com/

Hope this helps.